# How do i get a FB Canvas App to require user to be logged in?

Tags: facebook

I'm working with a Facebook Canvas App and I would like to only display the canvas app to people that are currently logged into facebook.  Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redirect them to the OAuth page. [Docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/canvas/)